# GORM Find By Foreign Key Association

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following `struct`:

```
type Relation struct {
    Metric *Metric `gorm:"foreignkey:MetricID"`
    MetricID uint
    ...
}
```

`Metric` is defined as:

```
type DatabaseMeta struct {
    Id uint `json:"-" gorm:"primary_key"`
}

type Metric struct {
    DatabaseMeta
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Medium string `json:"medium"`
}
```

I'd like to find a `Relation` from a value set in `Metric` using GORM, which has a FK association.

I tried:

```
var relation common.Relation
database.Preload("Relation.Metric").Where(&Relation{
    Metric: &Metric{
        Name: "temperature",
        Medium: "water",
    },
}).First(&relation)
```

Despite `Preload` and trying combinations of `Association` and `Preload` arguments, the following SQL is actually generated by GORM:

```
[2018-05-06 18:47:37]  sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type common.Metric, a struct
[2018-05-06 18:47:37]  [0.14ms]  SELECT * FROM "relations"  WHERE ("relations"."metric" = '{{0} temperature water}') LIMIT 1
[0 rows affected or returned ]
```

This works and is conceptually what I'm looking for:

```
// Look up the metric from `Name` and `Medium` fields
var metric Metric
database.Where(&Metric{
    Name: "temperature",
    Medium: "water",
}).First(&metric)

// Use the `metric` FK directly to search for the `relation`
var relation Relation
database.Where(&Relation{
    MetricID: metric.DatabaseMeta.Id,
}).First(&relation)
```

How can I use GORM to find a `struct` by a field set in its foreign key relation? Is this possible?